# Update Top n using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

How can I make NHibernate produce this t-sql request ?

Update top (n) Tasks
set MODIFICATIONS 
where CONDITION

I don't want to do a Transaction + batch update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check this:

- [13.3. DML-style operations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct)

a cited code snippet:

```
ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
string hqlVersionedUpdate = "update versioned Customer set name = :newName where name = :oldName";
int updatedEntities = s.CreateQuery( hqlUpdate )
        .SetString( "newName", newName )
        .SetString( "oldName", oldName )
        .ExecuteUpdate();
tx.Commit();
session.Close();
```

So, this way, we can defin UPDATE with HQL (using our domain model) and executing the udpate directly at once on DB side

*NOTE: for more details also check this blog post: [NHibernate – Executable DML](http://ayende.com/blog/4037/nhibernate-executable-dml) by Ayende*

Comment: I don't see the "Top" command here, I need to update juste 5 elements, I know I can do ExecuteSqlQuery, but then I'll have to check the DataProvider because the Top command is T-sql specific, in MySql we use Limit, I would liked that Nhibernate generate the specific query for me so it would work on all data providers.

Comment: I would say, we can have that! ;) Check this line in the doc: *"...Sub-queries may be used in the where-clause; the subqueries, themselves, may contain joins..."* use some TOP 5 query (subquery) to return proper set of IDs to be updated... and then use DML! ;) powerful NHibernate - check http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-subqueries

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will put it in a transaction for safety, one HQL query may ( or may not ) produce many sql queries ( if we query on a non-mapped base class for example ).

Comment: Enjoy NHibernate, sir. It is amazing tool ;)