# update records with special conditions nhibernate

Tags: sql, .net, nhibernate, where-clause, updatecommand

I have a table(InquiryTable) and first of all I select some records from it, after I extract these records from database, I update them into database. but I need to know how I can do these two commands simultaneously(merge them in one) by nhibernate.

```
inquiry = Session.Query<InquiryTable>().Where((c => c.ID == ID)).ToList();    
inquiry.FirstOrDefault().Time= sendTime;
Session.Update(inquiry);
```

I want to merge Session.Query and Session.Update in one command. It means that I need an update with where in same query.

Answer (score 0):

What would fit to this concept is NHiberante DML

> ## [13.3. DML-style operations](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct)
>
> As already discussed, automatic and transparent object/relational
>   mapping is concerned with the management of object state. This implies
>   that the object state is available in memory, hence manipulating
>   (using the SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements: INSERT,
>   UPDATE, DELETE) data directly in the database will not affect
>   in-memory state. However, NHibernate provides methods for bulk
>   SQL-style DML statement execution which are performed through the
>   Hibernate Query Language (HQL).

This feature set is **not** built on top of `ICriteria` or `QueryOver`, but it does use HQL.

An example from the doc, doing the UPDATE on filtered data in one shot:

```
string hqlUpdate = "update Customer c set c.name = :newName where c.name = :oldName";
// or string hqlUpdate = "update Customer set name = :newName where name = :oldName";
int updatedEntities = s.CreateQuery( hqlUpdate )
        .SetString( "newName", newName )
        .SetString( "oldName", oldName )
        .ExecuteUpdate();
```

See also:

- [Update Top n using NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25787388/1679310)
- [Do I have to refresh entities after bulk updates / deletes with HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26788120/1679310)